# Microphone internal not working on Acer Swift sf314-55G on Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, microphone

I am using Acer Swift sf314-55G and Ubuntu as Operating Systems. I have an issue when using the microphone internal, my microphone doesn't work but my speaker is okay, and when I use the external microphone it can work with an external microphone.